# Custom FormRequest redirects to web route in Laravel 11

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application in Laravel 11 that is configured as follows in the `app.php` file:

```
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
        apiPrefix: 'api/v0',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        //
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();
```

In `api.php` file, I have the following route:

```
Route::get('/updateAllMovies', [\App\Http\Controllers\APIController::class, 'updateAllMovies']);
```

Inside my `APIController`, I have this code:

```
public function updateAllMovies(APIRequest $request){
        $validated = $request->validated();

        if ($request->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $request->errors()], 422);
        }

        return response()->json(['success' => true], 200);
    }
```

And finally inside my `APIRequest` I have:

```
class APIRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'access_token' => 'required|exists:tokens_access,token'
        ];
    }

    public function messages(){
        return [
            'access_token.required' => 'O token de acesso é obrigatório na requisição.',
            'access_token.exists' => 'O token de acesso informado é inválido.'
        ];
    }
}
```

When I try to make a request to the `/updateAllMovies` route via postman (Sending the `access_token` or not.), I am redirected to the main route that exists in the `web.php` file.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Welcome to my Cinema API ';
});
```

I would like to understand why this is happening, why don't I continue on the `api.php` route and don't receive any error messages?

Comment: I am assuming you mean you send the request to `api/v0/updateAllMovies` ?

Comment: are you sending the appropriate headers with your request for the application to know you are expecting JSON as a response? without those the default of failed validation is to redirect 'back', and if there is no 'back' you would get a redirect to the root of the site .. also checking if validation fails in your controller won't do anything as the form request throws an exception when it fails validation so you never get into your controller method

Comment: Yes @apokryfos, I'm trying to send to api/v0/updateAllMovies

Comment: @lagbox, I'm sending in header: Content-Type: 'application/json' only.

Comment: that isn't the header that tells the server what you will accept as a response ... that is just saying what type of content the request is ....

Comment: Also send the header `Accept: application/json` because this (most of the time) prevents redirect responses from Laravel.  The redirect might be happening due to a validation failure but personally I don't recommend validating the access token in this way. Personally I would recommend you send it in a header and validate it in middleware instead of sending it in the body/query and validating it using request validation.